# 非同期処理において結果が思ったように出ない理由を知りたい

Tags: java, java8

Java8,非同期処理の勉強をしています。
以下のコードで出力結果の期待値は「200」です。

ただし、200がでたり、でなかったりします。
**その理由を教えて下さい。**

以下のリンク先からコードは取得しました。
https://qiita.com/subaru44k/items/d98ad79d21abccedb20b

出力処理である「thenAcceptAsync」が行われないことがあるとは考えづらいのですが、
なぜ出力されない時があるのか知りたいです。

ある値を返すのはSupplierで、変換はFunctionで、それを受け取って処理をするのはConsumerで実施する。という認識です。

よろしくお願いいたします。

```
package java8;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class CompletableFutureTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Supplier<Integer> initValueSupplier = () -> 100;
        Function<Integer, Integer> multiply = value -> value * 2;
        Consumer<Integer> valueConsumer = value -> System.out.println(value);

        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(initValueSupplier)
                .thenApplyAsync(multiply)
                .thenAcceptAsync(valueConsumer);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

非同期処理の完了を待たずに`main`メソッドが終了してしまうためでしょう。

`main`メソッド終了後、プロセスの終了処理が完了する前に`System.out.println(value)`の出力が完了していれば、コンソール等に結果が出力されますが、それが間に合わないと結果が何も(場合によっては一部しか)表示されないと言うことになります。

極めてわずかなタイミングの差なので、ほんの1msecだけ`main`の完了を遅らせてやれば、確実に出力される(*)ようになるはずです。

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Supplier<Integer> initValueSupplier = () -> 100;
        Function<Integer, Integer> multiply = value -> value * 2;
        Consumer<Integer> valueConsumer = value -> System.out.println(value);

        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(initValueSupplier)
                .thenApplyAsync(multiply)
                .thenAcceptAsync(valueConsumer);

        Thread.sleep(1); //<- `main`の完了を1msec遅らせる
    }
```

(*)「確実に出力される」のは、この問題に限っての話で、実際に非同期処理の終了を確実に完了するのを待つ場合には、yohjp さんのコメントなども参考にしてください。

Comment: sleepではタイミング依存問題を解決していないため、[`Future.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--)または[`CompletableFuture.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join--)で待機するほうが好ましいかもしれません。

Comment: @yohjp さん、コメントありがとうございます。ただこの回答の趣旨としては、「処理を確実に完了させる」ことではなく、「でたり、でなかったり」する「理由」を明らかにすることの方なので、主文の方はそのままにさせてもらいます。

Comment: 理由の説明としてはおっしゃる通りですね。ただ、この場合に限っても1msec sleepで「確実」と言い切ってしまうことには反対です。「非常に高い確率で」期待する動作が得られるだけです。並行処理に起因する不具合を、タイミング制御だけで解決しようとするのは禍根を残します。

Comment: @yohjp さん、私も「解決」方法として`sleep`なんて使っていれば同じ意見を書いたかもしれません。あなたのご主張は貴重な意見として承っておきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

> 出力処理である「thenAcceptAsync」が行われないことがあるとは考えづらいのですが、
>   なぜ出力されない時があるのか知りたいです。

`thenAcceptAsync`は確かに(メインスレッドで同期的に)実行されます。ただしこれは、言わば「実行の予約」であり、実際に実行されるかどうかは別の話です。

---

[`CompletableFuture#supplyAsync()`の説明](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier))にある通り、ここで登場する一連の `CompletableFuture` は [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) executor service が実行します。
そして[`ForkJoinPool`のワーカースレッドはデーモンスレッドです](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)。

> すべてのワーカー・スレッドは、Thread.isDaemon() set trueで初期化されます。

ここで、「デーモンスレッド」についての説明は[`Thread`のJavadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean))にあります:

> Java仮想マシンは、実行中のスレッドがデーモン・スレッドだけになると終了します。

さて、今回のコードを実行する上で登場するスレッドは2種類あります

- メインスレッド
- `ForkJoinPool` executor serviceのワーカースレッド

が、このうち非デーモンスレッドは前者メインスレッドだけであり、前述の通り後者はデーモンスレッドです。
つまり、メインスレッドが終了すれば「実行の予約」が存在しようとも実行されないままJVMは終了します。

(`ForkJoinPool`からすれば、実行完了まで待ちたければ[`join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#join())すればええやん、結果を受け取らないってことは実行してもせんでもええんやろ？ということですね)

---

ちなみに、[`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int))なんかで作成されるexecutor serviceのワーカスレッドは、[デフォルトでは非デーモンスレッドです](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#defaultThreadFactory())。
なので、

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ...

    // ExecutorService es = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(initValueSupplier, es)
        .thenApplyAsync(multiply, es)
        .thenAcceptAsync(valueConsumer, es);

}
```

といったふうに `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` を `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` で挿げ替えることでデーモンスレッド/非デーモンスレッドの違いが確認できるかと思います。

この場合も2種類のスレッド

- メインスレッド
- (`Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`によって生成される) `ThreadPoolExecutor` executor serviceのワーカスレッド

が登場することになりますが、今回はワーカスレッドも非デーモンスレッドであるためメインスレッドが終了してもJVMは終了しません(ので、結果的にタスクの実行は必ず実行されることになります)。

Comment: ありがとうございます！