# CompletableFutureを使った非同期処理を理解したい

Tags: java, java8

現在Java,Eclipse,Java1.8でCompletabelFutureによる非同期処理を勉強しています。

**以下のサイトにある次のコードを実装したのですが、コンソール出力されません。

なぜでしょうか？**（サイト上ではコンソール出力されると書いているのですが）

[CompletableFutureの公式ドキュメントを読んでも分からないので Java逆引きレシピを片手に理解する](https://qiita.com/bonobono555/items/97a678d6530c8a0b939d#thenapply%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)

```
    public class CompletableFutureTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        CompletableFuture<String> future1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> {
                    // 時間のかかる処理
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return "java1";
                });

        // thenApplyの場合
        future1
                .thenApply(
                        new Function<String, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public String apply(String res) {
                                return res; // resには、future1のreturnで定義した「java1」が入っている
                            }
                        })
                .thenApply(
                        res -> {
                            return res; // resには1回目のthenApplyの戻り値の「java1」が入っている
                        })
                .thenAccept(
                        new Consumer<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(String res) {
                                System.out.println(res); // resには2回目のthenApplyの戻り値の「java1」が入っており、コンソールに出力される
                            }
                        });
    }
}
```

ちなみにThread.sleep(1000);をThread.sleep(1);のように短くしたり、コメントアウトするとコンソール出力されます。動きとして、１秒後に返される戻り値を待てずにthenApply以降の処理が実行されているのかなと思います。

thenApply自体は前の処理の完了は待たないのでしょうか？「このステージが正常に完了したときに、このステージの結果を指定された関数への引数に設定して実行される新しいCompletionStageを返す。」だけであって。すなわち次の処理が同期処理になるだけでしょうか？

またもしそうだとした場合、著者の方はsleep処理を入れたと予想できますでしょうか？まるで１秒待ってから次の処理が実行されるようなリードですが。

もしわかる方がいればよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こちらの回答

- [非同期処理において結果が思ったように出ない理由を知りたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/67221/2808)

に記載した理由と同じです。
`Executor`を引数に取らない[`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync(java.util.function.Supplier))で得られたfutureは**デーモンスレッド**で処理されます。
ですのでメインスレッドが終了するとこのスレッドも終了します。
が、そのタイミングで`future1`が完了しているとは限りません。
(完了していなければ、当然、`thenApply()` 以降も実行されません。)

---

> thenApply自体は前の処理の完了は待たないのでしょうか？

待ちます。
ただし、今回の場合、そもそもその「前の処理」が完了しないうちにプロセスが終了しています。

---

なお、このデーモンスレッドがどうこうというのは`CompletableFuture`の本質には関係がないので、とりあえずこのようなサンプルコードを試す際には([この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/67202/2808)のように)`main`メソッドの最後に少し長めにスリープを入れる、としておけば`CompletableFuture`の学習に集中できるかと思います。
(参照されているようなコードサンプルでは、プロセスの生存期間は`CompletableFuture`実行時間に対して十分長いことが前提になっていると思います。)

Comment: ありがとうございます！